# Trying to filter a data frame - looking for set time periods where there is limited variation in another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and they are ordered by a time column with a time stamp every second. I want to search the data frame for 1-minute periods that have limited variation in another variable.

For example, I want every minute in the data frame where the TWS(true wind speed) has a variation of no more than 5 knots. These 1 minute periods should also not overlap.

Once we have the 1-minute sections, create another data frame with each minute of data averaged into rows.

Here is the head of the data

```
        Date                Time     Lat  Lon   AWA  AWS    TWA  TWS  
1 19/10/2018 2019-02-11 12:06:16 35.8952 14.5  -99.7 8.42  -99.7 8.42 
2 19/10/2018 2019-02-11 12:06:17 35.8952 14.5  -99.1 8.24  -99.1 8.24 
3 19/10/2018 2019-02-11 12:06:18 35.8952 14.5  -99.2 7.34  -99.2 7.34 
4 19/10/2018 2019-02-11 12:06:19 35.8952 14.5  -99.6 6.87  -99.6 6.87 
5 19/10/2018 2019-02-11 12:06:20 35.8952 14.5  -101.1 8.85 -101.1 8.85 
6 19/10/2018 2019-02-11 12:06:21 35.8952 14.5  -101.6 9.39 -101.6 9.39
```

Comment: next time, please use `dput()` to create sample data.. that way, others do not have to re-create your sample by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
   mutate(Date=as.Date(Date), Time=ymd_hms(Time)) %>% 
   group_by(gr=minute(Time)) %>% 
   mutate(flag=max(TWS,na.rm=TRUE)-min(TWS,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
   filter(flag<5) %>% 
   mutate_all(.,mean,na.rm=TRUE) %>% distinct()

# A tibble: 1 x 10
# Groups:   gr [1]
   Date       Time                  Lat   Lon   AWA   AWS   TWA   TWS    gr  flag
   <date>     <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 0019-10-20 2019-02-11 12:06:17  35.9  14.5 -99.3    8. -99.3    8.     6  1.08
```

For variation between elements in each group, we can use `dplyr::lag`:

```
... mutate(flag=TWS-lag(TWS, default = first(TWS))) %>% 
    filter(all(abs(flag)<5)) %>% mutate_all(.,mean,na.rm=TRUE) %>% distinct()
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Date                Time     Lat  Lon   AWA  AWS    TWA  TWS  
1 '19/10/2018' '2019-02-11 12:06:16' 35.8952 14.5  -99.7 8.42  -99.7 8.42 
2 '19/10/2018' '2019-02-11 12:06:17' 35.8952 14.5  -99.1 8.24  -99.1 8.24 
3 '19/10/2018' '2019-02-11 12:06:18' 35.8952 14.5  -99.2 7.34  -99.2 7.34 
4 '19/10/2018' '2019-02-11 12:07:19' 35.8952 14.5  -99.6 6.87  -99.6 6.87 
5 '19/10/2018' '2019-02-11 12:07:20' 35.8952 14.5  -101.1 8.85 -101.1 8.85 
6 '19/10/2018' '2019-02-11 12:07:21' 35.8952 14.5  -101.6 9.39 -101.6 16.39 
", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this kind of works but if I understand correctly it sorts it into minutes then looks for minutes with a set variation in TWS  as apposed to a rolling format that defines the minute around a set of values that have the correct variation.

Comment: Yes, I group by minute then filter those minutes with variation less than 5, finally, I took the average per minute. If I didn't get you correctly please provide the expected output with some explanations.